# Scraping data based on the text of other neighboring elements?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a code like this:

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="leftNav">
      <div id="leftNavContainer">
        <div id="refinements">
          <h2>Department</h2>

          <ul id="ref_2975312011">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <span class="expand">Pet Supplies</span>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <strong>Dogs</strong>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a>
                <span class="refinementLink">Carriers &amp; Travel Products</span>
                <span class="narrowValue">&nbsp;(5,570)</span>
              </a>
            </li>


(etc...)
```

Which I'm scriping like this:

```
html       = file
data       = Nokogiri::HTML(open(html))
categories = data.css('#ref_2975312011')

@categories_hash = {}
categories.css('li').drop(2).each do | categories |
  categories_title = categories.css('.refinementLink').text
  categories_count = categories.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/].delete(",").to_i
  @categories_hash[:categories] ||= {}
  @categories_hash[:categories]["Dogs"] ||= {}
  @categories_hash[:categories]["Dogs"][categories_title] = categories_count
end
```

So now. I want to do the same but without using `#ref_2975312011` and "Dogs".

So I was thinking I could tell Nokogiri the following:

> Scrap the `li` elements (starting from the third one) that are right
>   below the li element which has the text Pet Supplies enclosed by a link and a span tag.

Any ideas of how to accomplish that?

Comment: what do you mean by `starting from the third one` ? Can you clear your need a bit more? Still I am not clear about the need you are looking foe..

Comment: @Babai That part I have it done.  With `drop(2)`. Basically it's looping over the `li` elements and dropping the first two.

Comment: That's ok.. I just want to know your new need a more clearly,so that if possible I can help you.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pet Supplies `li` would be:

```
puts doc.at('li:has(a span[text()="Pet Supplies"])')
```

The following sibling `li`'s would be (skipping the first one):

```
puts doc.search('li:has(a span[text()="Pet Supplies"]) ~ li:gt(1)')
```

Comment: Okay.. this is what OP was looking for..Now I understood. Good..then :)

Comment: Or, in XPath: `next_lis = doc.xpath("//li[a[span='Pet Supplies']]/following-sibling::li")`